# Display report in Chart

Tags: c#, charts

hi i wanna make chart in my C# aplication (winform)
my goal is simple i wanna display in chart how many people choose A answer, B answer etc
something like this
[image: Chart]
in that chat use 35 value for 'y', i wanna make it dinamic based on how many total answer (Answer A + Answer B = 15 + 20)

i already try something like this
    // (Method A)

```
this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddY("Answer A");
this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddY("Answer A");
this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddY("Answer B");

//AND (method B)  
 this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddXY("Answer A", 1);
 this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddXY("Answer B", 1);
 this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddXY("Answer B", 2);
 this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddXY("Answer B", 3);
 this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddXY("Answer B", 4);
 this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddXY("Answer A", 2);
```

//result Method B
   [image]

but it's result not as i want
anyidea how to do it?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  Where is the age series plotted, and what is 'Answer A' that you are passing to AddXY?  Does that code even compile?  Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: @SteveWellens please check my edited post...it's clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int sumOfAnswerA = // get the sum of ppl choose A from your data
int sumOfAnswerB = // get the sum of ppl choose B from your data.
```

now you can set the points in your chart

```
this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddXY("Answer A", sumOfAnswerA );
this.myChart.Series["Answer"].Points.AddXY("Answer B", sumOfAnswerB );
```

Comment: If you have many sums, you may find it advantageous to use a dictionary as a histogram:  Dictionary<string, int>

Comment: @SteveWellens nice sugestion..but in this project max answer just 9...i guess i will try it later

Comment: It's not necessary.  Only do it if it makes the code simpler and clearer.